# getopt in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, getopt

I need to parse arguments using the `getopt` function. The problem is if I have arguments before and/or after options, `getopt` doesn't work. Option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered.

For exemple : `tftp ip port [-b blksize] src dest` doesn't work.
But `tftp [-b blksize] ip port src dest` works well.

Apparently, I need to add `+` at the beginning of `optstring` to be able to mix arguments and options but it doesn't supported on Max OS X according to https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/getopt.html

Have you a solution? Thanks.

Comment: That document seems to refer to OSX 10.5. We are on 10.10 these days, I think.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The version isn't going to matter, OS X is a BSD system. The BSD getopt does not support GNU extensions. Also I have the 10.11 man page open.

Comment: As an alternative you can use the very featureful [Gnome lib command line parser](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html).

Comment: Seems interesting, I'll use that for my personal use. Unfortunately, I'm doing a school project and I am not allowed to use third libraries :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change what you pass `getopt` in as `argv` and `argc` to skip over the command portion.

For example, `tftp ip port [-b blksize] src dest` you'd pretend `port` at `argv[2]` is `argv[0]`. Call `getopt(argc - 2, argv + 2, optstring)`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int ch;

    while( (ch = getopt(argc - 2, argv + 2, "b:")) != -1 ) {
        printf("%c %s\n", ch, optarg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is just an example. It's up to you to add the logic to determine if there is a command or subcommand.

Comment: I disagree. You presumably need to know if the options apply to the command in general vs the subcommand. This, for example, is [how git works](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/). If there's anything dirty here it's using short options. You should be using `getopt_long`.